# Creating ZIP folder with shutil - Python

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to use shutil.make_archive but it's duplicating the folder name. Let me explain better:

My folder `R360` to be ziped is located at: `C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Project\media\SAE\R360\`

What I am trying to do is: create a zip folder with this same name. So in the SAE directory, it should be the regular folder `R360` and then `R360.zip`.

My code:

```
folder = C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Project\media\SAE\R360
mediaFolder = C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Project\media\
shutil.make_archive(f'{folder}', 'zip', f"{mediaFolder}SAE/", f"{folder.split('/')[-1]}/")
```

The `R360.zip` is being created normally but the problem is that the zip folder is like this:

```
C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Project\media\SAE\R360.zip\R360\...
```

What I really wanted:

```
C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Project\media\SAE\R360.zip\...
```

It shouldn't be that `R360` inside the zip folder.

Comment: Is that actually your code? Your paths appear to be strings, but they're not quoted.

Comment: Yes, it's my code! It's kind of working but creating the folder itself inside the zip! I wish this R360 folder did not exist inside the R360.zip

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? `folder = C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Project\media\SAE\R360` isn't even valid Python, it would throw a syntax error.

Answer (score -2):

I'd like to post my own question for other who are facing the same issue!

```
folder = C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Project\media\SAE\R360
mediaFolder = C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Project\media\
shutil.make_archive(f'{folder}/', 'zip', f"{mediaFolder}SAE/{folder.split('/')[-1]}")
```

This will create the zip file, without duplicating the folder itself inside the zip!

Comment: Like your question, your answer is syntactically incorrect.